# What semantic notions underlie 妥 (suitable') with 爫 (爪 or claw) and 女?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

Reading [穩妥's etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A9%A9%E5%A6%A5) spurred me to read [妥's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A6%A5#Chinese). I screenshot [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E5%A6%A5#). I truly hope this etymology doesn't relate to the inhumane barbarism of [foot binding in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_binding)!

> ## Translingual
>
> #### Han character
>
> **妥** (*radical 38,* [女](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E5%A5%B3)+4, 7 strokes, *[cangjie input](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_Cangjie)* 月女 ([BV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_Cangjie/b)), *[four-corner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_four_corner)* [20404](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_four_corner/2), *[composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_description_languages#Ideographic_Description_Sequences)* ⿱[爫](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%88%AB)[女](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A5%B3))
>
> 1. [satisfactory](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/satisfactory), [appropriate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appropriate)

[image]

Comment: It can't possibly have anything to do with foot binding. The origination of Chinese characters predated the practice of foot binding by 2 millennia.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 views:

1.**At first, it means reassuring a woman with hands, so it also means be stable.**-Li Xiaoding

2.**At first, it means hold down the woman to let her sit down with a hand, so it also means be stable.**("爫" means a hand.)-Xu Zhongshu, Liu Xinglong

3.**At first, it means grab a woman by a hand, so it also means capture.**("爫" means a hand.)-Wu Qichang, Yu Xingwu, Xu Zaiguo

> 甲金文从爪（倒手）从「女」，象以手安抚女子之形，引申有安义（李孝定）。 《集韵》：「妥，安也。 或作绥。 」一说「妥」象以手按抑妇女使之坐下，引伸有安定之义（徐中舒、刘兴隆）。 一说「妥」象以手擒拿、抓取女子之形。 本义是俘掠，后作「绥」。 《书. 武成》，肆予东征，绥厥士女。 」师·马报簋：「孚士女羊牛。 」（吴其昌、于省吾、徐在国）。 「妥」与「孚」（「俘」的初文）的造字原理相同。 吴其昌认为甲骨文「男曰孚，女曰妥。 」
>
> ——[汉语多功能字库，香港中文大学](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A6%A5)

("妥" in Western Zhou dynasty)[image]

Comment: a woman under a roof is 'safe' (安); a woman with a son is 'good' (好); woman is related to evil (奸);